# SQL - regexp_extract JSON string

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract from the following string the locationID

`{"type":"player","topic_id":"555","topic_name":"sfd","userId":116,"userLocation":{"countryCode":"BR","locationId":21,"locationCity":"Rio de Janeiro"}}`

I'm able to extract for example the `topic_id` using the following `safe_cast(regexp_extract(h.events.label,r'"topic_id":"([a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+)"') as int64`
but this doesn't work for `locationId`. I'm guessing it's because of the nested dict? But not sure how to get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better using a *json* function rather than a *regexp* function.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT '{"type":"player","topic_id":"555","topic_name":"sfd","userId":116,"userLocation":{"countryCode":"BR","locationId":21,"locationCity":"Rio de Janeiro"}}' json 
)
SELECT CAST(JSON_VALUE(json, '$.userLocation.locationId') AS INT64) AS locationId 
  FROM sample_data;

+------------+
| locationId |
+------------+
|         21 |
+------------+
```

> this doesn't work for `locationId`. I'm guessing it's because of the nested dict?

- I guess it's because a value of `topic_id` is a string `"555"` and a value of `locationId` is an integer `21`.
- `r'"locationId":([a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+)'` will work for `locationId` but   more simple regular expression would be `r'"locationId":(\d+)'`

Comment: The json function worked thank you!!